# Class with PDO function / Cant call another function within class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a DB class with a connect function that returns a new PDO.

On the other page I declare `$db = DB::connect();` and do all my calculations.

I have then passed a function called   `echo DB::startSession($username);` on my main page.

I now use the startSession($username) function to start a pdo and execute a query. Although whenever I use something like `$connect = self::connect();` I get an error, same with `$connect = $this->connect();`

All code

```
public static function connect(){

      $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=chatsite;host=127.0.0.1';
      $user = 'root';
      $password = 'root';

      try {
          $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
          return $dbh;
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
          echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
      }
    }



public static function startSession($username){

      //return "user: " . $username;
      $active_check = self::connect();
      $active_check->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
      $active_check->execute();

      return 'test';
```

And this is on the other page

```
echo DB::startSession($username);
```

The error I get is Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() which has something to do with the PDO not being activated in the first line.

Comment: Its not a duplicate thats not my question

Comment: `$query = $active_check->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'"); $query->execute();`?

Comment: [**Your class will kill your database server.**](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Comment: @Rasclatt Thank you, honestly missed that. Overthinking this! haha

Comment: @YourCommonSense how come?

Comment: Your comment didn't help either

Comment: That's what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $active_check = self::connect();
 $stmt = $active_check->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
 $stmt->execute();
```